# Increasing MIU of LLCP for NDEF connection to android

Tags: android, nfc-p2p

How do I increase the MIU from the default 128 to 255 when transporting data over LLCP?
I'm using a Galaxy S4 Mini with CyanogenMod12 as my test phone and a microcontroller connected to a PN532.
When I send an NdefMessage from my PN532 to Android I can send message up to 255Bytes in one frame, but when I send a message from Android to the PN532 it is only able to send 132Bytes.
I think it is related to the MIU.
Since I didn't find any information how to set the MIU on Android, I set it for the PDU CC and PDU CONNECT of my microcontroller.
Like this:

```
llcpp->ssap = getDSAP(llcpp->headerBuf);
llcpp->dsap = getSSAP(llcpp->headerBuf);
/* Put a ConnectionComplete (CC) PDU to respond on the Connect PDU */
llcpp->headerBuf[0] = (llcpp->dsap << 2) + ((PDU_CC >> 2) & 0x3);
llcpp->headerBuf[1] = ((PDU_CC & 0x3) << 6) + llcpp->ssap;
// MIUX in TVL format.
llcpp->headerBuf[2] = MIUX_TYPE; // Type: 0x02
llcpp->headerBuf[3] = MIUX_LENGTH; // Length: 0x02
llcpp->headerBuf[4] = 0x07; // 5Bits 0, first 3Bits of MIUX 1.
llcpp->headerBuf[5] = MIUX_256; // MIUX: 0xff
llcpp->headerBuf[6] = RW_TYPE;
llcpp->headerBuf[7] = RW_LENGTH;
llcpp->headerBuf[8] = RW_2;
if(!macLinkWrite(llcpp->link, llcpp->headerBuf, 9))
  return -2;
```

But Android still uses `128` as the MIU.
Do I also have to set it on Android and/or does any body have experiences with LLCP?

best,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

The MIU is a receiver commitment. The sender will only utilize it up to it's own send capabilities, either some send buffer size or a lazy programmer's #define. There is no way to force an unwilling sender using more.

Note that when using SNEP (aka. Android Beam) it should be possible to get almost any size of NDEF message across, limited by the time it takes. The SNEP protocol implementation will fragment into appropriate segments of min(send-buffer, recv-buffer).